# Installing VMware tools on a Mac OSX VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, osx-snow-leopard, vmware

I know it's possible to install VMware tools on a Mac OSX VM, but I can't figure out how to do it or where to download them.

I'm using VMware Workstation with a Snow Leopard guest VM. The host OS is Windows 7.

Where can I download VMware Tools for Mac OS, and how do I install them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand it, this move isn't supported by either Apple or VMware. However, there are many hackers on the Internet who have reported to successfully installed OS X either directly on their PC or in a VM like you're trying to do. One article at [Online Tech Tips](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/mac-os-x/install-snow-leopard-on-pc/) states in a comment (emphasis mine):

> Best fix for display resolution is to get the **darwin.iso containing the Mac VMWare tools** from a VMWare Fusion installation off a MAc (it’s under Library/ApplicationSupport/Images.

It's actually under /Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/isoimages on an OS X machine with VMware Fusion installed. If you can get your hands on that iso, you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/

If not, maybe you could clarify your question.

Comment: Michael is using VMware Workstation in Windows 7, with Snow Leopard installed as a virtual machine. VMware Fusion will not work in this case.